# How to extract the value with the key field in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, key, dto

```
Map<string,DTO> DTOmap
```

The hash map has string as the key and the DTO as the value field in a hashmap
I am trying to get the DTO values printed in an excel sheet.
Can I use

```
Set<string> rows=DTOmap.keyset();
For(string key:rows)
Object[] objArr =DTOmap. Get(key);
For (Object obj:objArr){
Cell cell=row.createCell(cellnum++);
```

Can I use the above method to get all the DTO values using the key field to extract it?

Comment: `Object[] objArr =DTOmap. Get(key)` will not compile for a `Map<string,DTO>`. Why do you expect this to work? And why is your question "can I use..", have you not even tried to compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(string key:rows){
 Object[] objArr =DTOmap.get(key);
}
```

This is invalid. Your map is `Map<string,DTO>` , by calling `.get(key)` you will get a single DTO instance not an array of it.
You need to store all the DTO instances in an array / List for all keys.
Something like this :

```
List<DTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(String key:rows){
 DTO dto = DTOmap.get(key);
 list.add(dto);
}
```

After that you can do whatever you want iterating the list.

```
for(DTO dto : list){
 //your code 
}
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned by [@f1sh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214525/f1sh) in the comments .You can do the same just by iterating the `map.keyset()`

```
for(String key : DTOmap.keyset()){
 DTO dto = DTOmap.get(key);

 //your code
 Cell cell=row.createCell(cellnum++);
}
```

It is pointless to use two `for-loop` to perform some operation which can be done in one.

Comment: Why do you need a list for that? You can do the same logic without the List, while iterating over the `Map`'s `keySet()`.

Comment: Yeah true ,As per the question standard I just wanted to OP have the basic understanding. Will update once I have some free time

Comment: You can check the post for better understanding .

Comment: When I do follow this process and set the cell value I get a warning saying 'condition for obj instance of string' is always false'

Comment: @ShiBui I believe it is not related to this thread . You can create a new thread asking this as a  question with providing sufficient information.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya https://stackoverflow.com/q/72773951/19294975 could you please take a look at this too